# mysql show data max and sum from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I  have two tables and want to display the results for MAX of SUM total, group by name and month. 
only display maximum data from the total SUM results every month and group by name.
this my table

```
table t2
+-------+-------+-------+
| month | total | id_t3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |  15   |   1   |
|   1   |  20   |   2   |
|   1   |  50   |   1   |
|   2   |  40   |   2   |
|   2   |  20   |   3   |
|   2   |  20   |   1   |
|   3   |  10   |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

```
table t3
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  |  brian |
| 2  |  jessi |
| 3  |  redy  |
+----+---------
```

```
i want result 
+-------+---------------+
| month | total |  name |
+-------+---------------+
|   1   |  65   | brian |
|   2   |  40   | jessi |
|   3   |  10   | redy  |
+-------+---------------+
```

And this my query SQL

```
select t2.month, MAX(total), t3.name
from (
select t2.month, SUM(t2.total)as total, t3.name
from t2, t3
where t2.idt3 = t3.id
group by t2.month, t3.name
)result
group by t2.month, t3.name
order by total DESC
```

Comment: are you using `MySql 8.0`?

Comment: Please add your query.

Comment: your result is just group by month?

Comment: @zealous use Server Version: 10.4.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: @GilangPratama yes, the result just group by month, but total group by name results in the same month

Comment: so, do you want to group it by two column?

Comment: @GilangPratama yes, i want to group by two column, example i want to group same name ' brian' just in month 1 and select max total data group by month

Comment: @P.Salmon qusetion updated for query

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will solve your problem. `group by` month and name

```
select t2.month, SUM(t2.total), t3.name
from t2
join t3 on t2.id_t3 = t3.id
group by t2.month, t3.name
order by t2.total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum name per month, use window functions:

```
select month, name, total
from (select t2.month, t3.name, sum(t2.total) as total
             row_number() over (partition by t2.month order by sum(t2.total) desc) as seqnum
      from t2 join
           t3
           on t2.id_t3 = t3.id
      group by t2.month, t3.name
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by month;
```